# Should Windows K8s nodes have aws-node & kube-proxy pods?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I have this mixed cluster which shows all the nodes as Ready (both Windows & Linux ones). However, only the Linux nodes have aws-node & kube-proxy pods. I RDPed into a Windows node and can see a kube-proxy service.

My question remains: do the Windows nodes need aws-node & kube-proxy pods in the kube-system namespace or do they work differently than Linux ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kube-proxy` pods are part of default installation of Kubernetes. They are automaticaly created, and are needed on both Linux and Windows.

> kube-proxy is a network proxy that runs on each node in your cluster, implementing part of the Kubernetes Service concept.
>
> kube-proxy maintains network rules on nodes. These network rules allow network communication to your Pods from network sessions inside or outside of your cluster.
> <sup>[[source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-proxy)]</sup>

`aws-node` pod is a part of AWS CNI plugin for Kubernetes

> The Amazon VPC Container Network Interface (CNI) plugin for Kubernetes is deployed with each of your Amazon EC2 nodes in a Daemonset with the name `aws-node`. The plugin consists of two primary components:
> *[...]*
> <sup>[[source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-networking.html)]</sup>

It is currently only supported on Linux. Windows nodes are using a different CNI plugin - [vpc-shared-eni](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-plugins/tree/master/plugins/vpc-shared-eni)